# Is it good/safe OOP practice to have a method whose only purpose is to send/retrieve data from another class?

Tags: php, object-oriented, code-reviews

I have a class that performs basic MySQL operations. This is all in PHP.

```php
class dbTables {
    public $name;
    protected $fields = array(); // array of dbTableField objects
    public $result_sets = array();
    protected $primary_key; // filled using getFields() from __construct()


    public function __construct($table_name) {
        $this->name = $table_name;
        $this->getFields();
    }
    public function removeWhitespace($table_name) {
        $this->name = $table_name;
        $this->getFields();
    }
    // etc...
}
```

So all you need is the table name to create the object, and construct automatically gets a bunch of field data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (names, data types, etc).

I also have a method for removing whitespace from a column  It's currently located in another class, but I'm thinking of moving into the above `dbTables` class. You can see the method below. I don't think it's really necessary to read the method to answer my question, but it could be helpful.

```php
protected function removeWhiteSpace($target_field,$abbrev_field,$from_size,$to_size,$options) {
    // optional conditions based on original character length and resulting character length.
    /* options: from_size = all/longer_than/shorter_than
    *   to_size = all/longer_than/shorter_than
    */
    $temp_table = $this->table_name;        
    $sql = "UPDATE `$temp_table` 
        SET `undo_sku` = `$target_field`, `$target_field` = REPLACE(`$target_field`,' ',''), `$abbrev_field` = 'w'";
    $where = array();
        if($options['from_size'] == 'longer_than') {
            $where[] = "`$target_field` > $from_size";
        } else if($options['from_size'] == 'shorter_than') {
            $where[] = "`$target_field` < $from_size";
        }
        if($options['to_size'] == 'longer_than') {
            $where[] = "LENGTH(REPLACE(`$target_field`,' ','')) > $to_size";
        } else if($options['from_size'] == 'shorter_than') {
            $where[] = "LENGTH(REPLACE(`$target_field`,' ','')) < $to_size";
        }               
        //WHERE `$target_field` = '' AND LENGTH(REPLACE(`vnd_sku`,' ','')) <= $string_length";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Now, if I do move it into `dbTables`, I will still want to use the functionality in the other class. Should I just instantiate a `dbTables` object whenever I need to use `removeWhitespace`? Or, could I give `dbTables` its own `removeWhitespace` method like this:

```php
protected function removeWhiteSpace($target_field,$abbrev_field,$from_size,$to_size,$options) {
  /* options: from_size = all/longer_than/shorter_than
  * to_size = all/longer_than/shorter_than
  */
  $dbtable = new dbTables($this->table_name);
  $temp_table = $this->table_name;

  $result = $dbtable->removeWhiteSpace($target_field,$abbrev_field,$from_size,$to_size,$options);
  return $result;
}
```

The advantage I see is that now I have a way to limit instantiation of the `dbTables` object in various other classes. Methods that need to use `removeWhiteSpace` can use `$this->removeWhiteSpace` instead of instantiating a `dbTables` object. The class's own `removeWhiteSpace` method takes care of that.

I'm kind of new to OOP, though, so I'm just wondering if that is good practice or bad.

I also hope I'm asking this question in the right place. I'm pretty sure it's not a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code smell here is that you have multiple classes that hold table *names*.

Good object-oriented design calls for a class that wraps a table (which itself holds reference to class that wraps database connection) and using that to refer to tables in all the other classes.

I suspect that's what you are aiming at with the `dbTables` class. So yes, move the method there, but replace the `table_name` field in the other class with reference to `dbTables` instance, so the wrapper just says `$this->table->removeWhitespace(...)`.

Comment: Indeed I have run into problems due to my early use of table names. Are you recommending that I pass objects as parameters to other objects' methods, rather than strings/numbers? The "client" object could then use the parameter-object's methods to manipulate it or get data out of it?

Comment: @ButtleButkus: You should be passing around objects. It gives you better checking, because it will fail quickly (on missing attribute) if you pass wrong type and it will hide the dereferencing inside the methods. Stop if it would make the code longer or more complicated though.

Answer (score 5):

If you find yourself wanting to instantiate an object (e.g. `dbTables`) just to access one bit of very specific functionality in it, without actually using that object for what it is, then it's usually a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and a sign you need to portion up your code a little differently.

Why not factor out your removal of whitespace functionality, in a reusable and context-free a way as possible, into some sort of utility class? Then this can be accessed from all the places needing the functionality.

Alternatively, leave the function where it is, but make it static (class level), so that it can be called without using an instance of the class it's in.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. The removeWhitespace function in my example would go through a database table and remove the whitespace from every single column. I'm not sure if it would actually make sense for it to be in a utility class, which might have to work on plain strings, database tables, and database columns. What do you think?